# trigger click event from angularjs directive

Tags: events, angularjs, click, angularjs-directive

How can i trigger a click event for li elements specifying their index from the angularjs directive?
I have tried using $first for triggering click for the first element, but its not working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to trigger click event via the code? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to display images in a list. I want to display the first image by default when the page loads. Please see the plunker below. As of now i am doing that using jQuery timeout function which is not optimal solution, but need to change that to angularjs. http://plnkr.co/edit/CVnp9FKcIMr7GoSpfcoX

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is perhaps a different way for you to achieve this.  Pass into the directive both the index and the item and let the directive setup the html in a template:

Demo:   http://plnkr.co/edit/ybcNosdPA76J1IqXjcGG?p=preview

html:

```
<ul id="thumbnails">
    <li class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="item in items" options='#my-container' itemdata='item' index="$index">

    </li>
  </ul>
```

js directive:

```
app.directive('thumbnail', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'CA',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
        index: '=index',
        item: '=itemdata'
    },
    template: '<a href="#"><img src="{{item.src}}" alt="{{item.alt}}" /></a>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        if (parseInt(scope.index) == 0) {
            angular.element(attrs.options).css({'background-image':'url('+ scope.item.src +')'});
        }

        elem.bind('click', function() {
            var src = elem.find('img').attr('src');

            // call your SmoothZoom here
            angular.element(attrs.options).css({'background-image':'url('+ scope.item.src +')'});
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

You probably would be better off adding a ng-click to the image as pointed out in another answer.

**Update**

The link for the demo was incorrect.  It has been updated to: http://plnkr.co/edit/ybcNosdPA76J1IqXjcGG?p=preview

Comment: guys, what do we mean by restrict ='CA' in the above example? I have seen C and A but what is CA?

Comment: @MohammadUmairKhan Please see the directive documentation on the angular site.  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @lucuma yes I did see that but I did not understand how can a combination of the 2 can be made use of, the idea that i had was that we are able to use only one of the ECMA

Comment: If you specify more than one say EA your directive can be either an element or a class.

Comment: @lucuma Your code can lead to unexpected behavior.
Try to select images in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/V5FRHB5Q3LeMSq6If7DM?p=preview

You should use `$apply` in jQuery `bind` (set `useApply = true` in above example).
Or you should use `ng-click` (set `useNg = true`).

Please update your answer.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you need to specify `replace: false` and `transclude: false`.

Answer (score 8):

This is more the Angular way to do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/xYNX47EsYvl4aRuGZmvo?p=preview

1. I added $scope.selectedItem that gets you past your first problem (defaulting the image)
2. I added $scope.setSelectedItem and called it in `ng-click`.  Your final requirements may be different, but using a directive to bind `click` and change `src` was overkill, since most of it can be handled with template
3. Notice use of [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) to avoid errant server calls on initial load
4. You'll need to adjust some styles to get the image positioned right in the div.  If you really  need to use `background-image`, then you'll need a directive like ngSrc that defers setting the `background-image` style until after real data has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension to Langdon's answer with a directive approach to the problem. If you're going to have multiple galleries on the page this may be one way to go about it without much fuss.

Usage:

```html
<gallery images="items"></gallery>
<gallery images="cats"></gallery>
```

[See it working here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Te0EmRxxAXUpIv4197r?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to trigger a button click when the page loads.

```
<li ng-repeat="a in array">
  <a class="button" id="btn" ng-click="function(a)" index="$index" on-load-clicker>
    {{a.name}}
  </a>
</li>
```

A simple directive that takes the index from the ng-repeat and uses a condition to call the first button in the index and click it when the page loads.

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
        .directive('onLoadClicker', function ($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    index: '=index'
                },
                link: function($scope, iElm) {
                    if ($scope.index == 0) {
                        $timeout(function() {

                            iElm.triggerHandler('click');

                        }, 0);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```

This was the only way I was able to even trigger an auto click programmatically in the first place.  `angular.element(document.querySelector('#btn')).click();`  Did not work from the controller so making this simple directive seems most effective if you are trying to run a click on page load and you can specify which button to click by passing in the index. I got help through this stack-overflow answer from another post reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495541/4684183 onLoadClicker Directive.

Comment: If you are going to down vote please explain why. You don't help the community by being negative without explanation. I posted this above answer because the other solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: it was probably someone trying to grief you. happens to me all the time. at least my upvote takes you back to 0 \\_shrug_/