# binding a css class to a element via angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to attach a directive to a element. The directive will be responsible for the following:
1. Attach a click event to the element
2. Upon click.. show a drop-down

In order to perform the first activity I have added directive called "sortDirective" to my element  below:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" style="font-size:0.6em" sort-directive></span>
```

This is done in the file layout.html

I am facing two issues:
1. the click event is not working
2.  the drop-down should be shown only on click event. Right now you will notice that the drop-down (blue in color) is being shown at all the times.

I believe i am missing something here since my directive sort-directive is falling within another directive custom-table. 
Am I thinking in the right direction or am I totally off ?

[Plnkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MD8AsUSH0vrb2GlJORmv)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call the click event with the directive. My advice would be just to put `ng-click` to the span that you want to call the function from (and move the function to the controller). 
You might want to look at this thread: 
[trigger click event from angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151595/trigger-click-event-from-angularjs-directive)

Also a quick css tip - add these rules

```
cursor:pointer;
padding:0 0 0 5px;
```

to the class `.header-cells`. 
Finally, don't you think that the arrow is too small to click it? Try binding the click event to the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

i finally managed to lay this out. Those interested in seeing how it is done ..here is a plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/TG6aCEu2TgPq28Jcj0nM?p=info

just click on any of the headers (in orange) and you should see the results.