# automatically click button after page load in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, click

I am looking to know if there is a way to perform a button click automatically on an angularjs page once the page loads based on a querystring value. For example in a simple asp.net web forms page if a querystring in a url is true then I can simply call `Button1_Click(sender,e);` to handle the click event in the page load. But this HTML5 page uses angularjs and I just cant seem to figure out how to do it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Maybe I wasnt clear enough in my explanation...my bad. But here goes..This is what I intend to do.[Since I cant post pictures yet...]

```
http://host/app/Quik.aspx?Order=5779809
```

UI:

```
TxtLookupNum: {{InputValue}}    DdlWMS:{{WMSKey}}    DdlWsNum: {{WorkStationName}}
btnLookup:Submit
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.Lookup = function(WMSKey,InputValue,WSNum);
```

When my aspx page has a query string parameter I'd like to automatically trigger a click event and pass the 3 parameters to my angular method like above.

This is how I wrote it and it worked but:

```
var inputVal = $('#txtLookupNum'); 
if (inputVal.val() != "") {$("#btnLookup").trigger("click");}
```

But now I am getting the below error:

> TypeError: **Cannot read property '0' of undefined** [after stripping out all the stack trace]

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it can be a custom directive. Directive `onLoadClicker` in the attached snippet clicks the element on which it is defined once the directive is *rendered* - in your case on the page load.

The `ng-click="wasClicked()"` is there just for control that it was really clicked, see browser console. That's also why I defined priority of `-1`, because `ng-click`s priority is `0`.

You just need to provide your logic (wrap the `$timeout` in an `if()`) on when to do it and when not to (for example based on [routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)).

*Note*: $timeout is there to make Angular world aware of the click (will run digest cycle), without it Angular would not notice something happened.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.wasClicked = function() {
      console.log('I was clicked!');
    }
  }
]);

myApp.directive('onLoadClicker', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: -1,
      link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElm.triggerHandler('click');
        }, 0);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="wasClicked()" on-load-clicker>link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to call a function during onload , then try this

```
var init = function () {
   // check if there is query in url
   // and fire search in case its value is not empty
};
// and fire it after definition
init();


// register controller in html
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="init()"></div>

// in controller
$scope.init = function () {
    // check if there is query in url
    // and fire search in case its value is not empty
};
```

Comment: The above solution is added from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load